# Editing Contents of Fallout 4 .ba3 Files

Tags: fallout-4

Is it possible to change the contents of Fallout 4's .ba3 data files?

I understand that there is a utility to view the contents, but they cannot be edited (such as removing files from inside the Sounds.ba3, for example).

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes and requests to close? This is about a game and it's utilities, which is on topic.

Comment: Maybe edit the part out that may look like you are asking for a utility recommendation

Comment: This is very close to asking for help modding a game which is off topic.  And by modding I mean making a mod not installing a mod someone else made.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion, and I would appreciate help with clarifying this. I only wish to know about modifying those ba3 files, I never asked with the intention to mod my game.

Answer (score -1):

Try the B.A.E. Bethesda Archive Extractor from the Nexus. 
But I recommend you not to randomly delete soundfiles from the gamearchives, as that may lead your game to crashes.
(I don't think the game handles broken references to files safely, as deleteing files from the archive will break references.)
So usage on own risk. (And prepare to restore the archive)